# Understanding output of prop.test in R

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, confidence-interval, proportion

Specifically, I wish to understand the meaning of the confidence interval. An example:

```
p1 = 0.02
p2 = 0.01
n1 = 10000
n2 = 1000
sig.level = 0.05

prop.test(x = c(p1*n1, p2*n2),
          n = c(n1, n2),
          alternative = "greater",
          conf.level = 1-sig.level)

# 2-sample test for equality of proportions with continuity correction
#
# data:  c(p1 * n1, p2 * n2) out of c(n1, n2)
# X-squared = 4.3353, df = 1, p-value = 0.01867
# alternative hypothesis: greater
#  95 percent confidence interval:
#  0.003785395 1.000000000
# sample estimates:
# prop 1 prop 2 
# 0.02   0.01
```

We have a `p-value = 0.01867 < 0.05` implying statistical significance at the 5% level. We also have the 95% confidence interval of `0.003785395 1.000000000`. The `prop.test` documentation states that:

> `conf.int` a confidence interval for the true proportion if there is one group, or for the difference in proportions if there are 2 groups and p is not given, or NULL otherwise....

1. In my example, the difference in proportions is `diff = p1 - p2 = 0.01`. So is this test saying that the true difference in proportions with a 95% CI is between `~0.0038` and `1`?
2. If so, is it correct to say that the sample difference is `1%` but the true difference could be as low as `0.38%` or as high as `100%`, with a 95% CI, and `p1` is greater than `p2` with `p<0.05`?
3. Is the upper CI bound of exactly `1` cause to be concerned with the validity of the results?

Comment: 1.   Your test and consequently your confidence interval is one-sided; some care is needed when trying to interpret one-sided intervals (compare with a two-sided interval for `conf=0.9`)... 2. You cannot get an observed  proportion of $0.01$ when $n=975$. You can get ~0.00923 or ~0.01026 but nothing in between.

Comment: 1. Yes, some care is needed, this is what I'm trying to understand with this question - how to interpret the confidence interval in this one-sided example. Can you help with this? 2. You are right, I didn't check that. I don't think it changes the essence of the question, but I can modify it to use possible proportions.

Comment: Notice that the CI with `alternative = "greater"`, and without continuity correction (i.e. `prop.test(x = c(p1*n1, p2*n2), n = c(n1, n2), alternative = "greater", conf.level = 1 - sig.level, correct = F)` is calculated as `(CI = c((p1 - p2) - qnorm(conf.level) * sqrt(p1 * (1 - p1)/n1 + p2 * (1 - p2)/n2), 1))`.

Comment: Which implies that the upper limit is set to $1$ by design. While the lower limit is $p1 - p2 - \text{qnorm(conf.level)}\times \sqrt{\frac{p1(1-p1)}{n1}+\frac{p2(1-p2)}{n2}}$.

Comment: Thanks Antoni. How can I interpret this in a sentence, with respect to my example? "The difference in proportions $p_1$ and $p_2$ is 1%, with a lower bound on the CI of 0.38%, and $p_1$ is greater than $p_2$ with $p<0.05$"?

Comment: This question received a downvote yesterday but no comment as to why. If you let me know why I can learn and try to improve the question.

Comment: This certainly seems clear enough to me. I'm voting to leave open.